# How to extract/identify word or text from the given text using stanford-nlp or OpenNLP via java

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am about to extract some information from the RAW tests published in Social Media, News sites, blogs which are related to a specific field such as politics, WAR, DRUGS etc. So I am already started to use some open source libs such as stanford-nlp, apache OpenNLP as well as a commercial licensed tool called lexalytics.

According to my project, we are analyzing text posted in publicly and generating some results and doing mining based on some parameters to identify those post are related to what category.

But I need to extract topics from the given text using stanford-nlp library. Topic means text or sentences related to EDUCATION, POLITICS such that. Already I am able to extract entities like text/sentences contain LOCATION, DATE, PERSON, MONEY such a way.

Same topic extraction coming with lexalytics as well which is licenses tool.

your help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As well as better if can show summary if the text/paragraph and also extract themes as well.

Comment: can you give a sample document?

Comment: or a couple ....

Comment: @Daniel you  can take any raw text from news site or social media. I have sample input but cannot attached to here. Since cannot attach attachments.

Comment: You can just include it in your msg.

Comment: @Daniel pls find the sample input and output from below link. I prefer these
\n
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzI7BYyJHndsd0tBaFVOWXdCT28

Im expecting below extractions:

1. Document overview  
2. Document themes   
3. Document Intentions  
4. Sentiment analysis  
5. Entity extraction  
6. Topic determination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topic extraction from text documents can be done using generative modeling where words distributed are assumed a prior based on topic(s) for which algorithms like LDA are deployed

Open Calais API `http://www.opencalais.com/opencalais-api/` gives you single/multiple topics with associated confidence values on which the document was based.